# Powershell ACL on file share

Tags: powershell, acl

I am working on a script and I am stuck trying to grant an AD group modify permissions to a share path. Currently when ran it does add the group to the folder but only with "list" permissions. Any ideas?

```
$groupname = "group_users"
$fullsharepath = "\\severname\servervol\share"


$acl = Get-Acl $fullsharepath
$permission = "domain\$groupname","Modify", [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit", [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $fullsharepath -Verbose
```

Comment: The code is working for me. are you sure your domain name is called `domain`?

Comment: I have modified this for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working for me, knowing that your domain name is `domain`.
Else, just remove `domain` from `"domain\$groupname"` if you are on the same domain as the group.

Below is another example, that is more simplified:

```
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path "\\severname\servervol\share"
$groupname = "group_users" #or "yourDomain\group_users"

$Ace = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$groupname","Modify", "ContainerInherit", "None", "Allow")

#Append the ACE to the ACL
$ACL.AddAccessRule( $Ace )

#Push settings
Set-Acl -AclObject $ACL $fullsharepath
```

Comment: So when you run this on your side it sets modify permissions? I just tried again but im only getting list...

Comment: Yes, it sets `modify` permissions, maybe you yourself don't have permissions to the share?

Comment: I can set the permissions manually in the GUI.

Comment: Update... So it does set the modify permissions... I missed it because the GUI initially only shows list and special... I also noticed its saying This folder and subfolders vs This folder and subfolders,files.. I assume that is what I need to change.

Comment: Then you add `"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"` in the permission. If you want even files to include in the scope.

Comment: Yup that did it. Was just coming back to report answered. :D